# pausing a thread from a function and resuming it

Tags: python, multithreading

I have many threads in my program as written below. I wanted to pause all the threads when one particular function is called from a thread, and then should resume after function execution of that function is finished or after a delay of 1 second. For example in the code below, I would like to pause threads switch1 and switch2 when switch3 is being executed, and then resume these threads after switch2 finishes execution or after a elay of 1 second.

Can anyone please let me know how I could implement in the code below ?

```
def switch1():
    if (buttonpressed ==1):
     print 1

def switch2():
    if (buttonpressed1 ==1):
     switch3()
     print 1

def switch3():
    if (buttonpressed2 ==1):
     print 1

def main():
    switch1thread=threading.thread(target=switch1)
    switch2thread=threading.thread(target=switch2)
    switch1thread.start()
    switch2thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not pause and resume threads without the cooperation of thread itself. The thread you want to pause or resume can pause and resume itself by checking some flags.
E.g. you can set some flag before executing `switch3` . `switch2` and `switch1` will pause themselves if that flag is set.